# @import make me confuse

Tags: sass, compass-sass

in compass or sass old version it can `@import` one times for every file like this

_mixin.sass

```
=test_mixin()
    color: #AAFFCB
```

screen.scss

```
@import "include/_mixin";
@import "print.scss";
header{ @include test_mixin; }
```

print.scss

```
header{ @include test_mixin; }
```

output screen.css

```
header {
  color: #aaffcb;
}
header {
  color: #aaffcb;
}
```

output print.css

```
header {
  color: #aaffcb;
}
```

it should no have any error but in new version have error 
`error sass/print.scss (Line 5: Undefined mixin 'test_mixin'.)`
i know add `@import "_mixin.scss"` to print.scss solve this but i think if future i want to chage `_mixin.scss` file name and if i have many file include `_mixin.scss` i think it too tired T^T

sorry for my bad english

how can i sovle this problem ?

thank :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some basics: 
Those SCSS files you don't want to be generated into independent CSS file, you name with an underscore at the beginning, e.g. `_mixin.scss`, it then will be your **partial**.
And files you want to have as a **separate CSS** file you name as usual without underscore, e.g. `screen.scss`.

Then, when you want to use your partial in your `screen.scss`, you do `@import`:

```
@import "path_to_your_partials/mixin"
```

(note, you don't need that underscore when importing).
Then and only then you can use some mixin from it:

```
@include colorize;
```

You include only partials (files with _) in your stand-alone CSS file, not files you want to be generated as CSS, so in your example in `screen.scss`, `@import "print.scss";` is excessive.

But wait, it gets better!

**Partials, which are included in same file, can access each other**, so you don't do any additional `@import` in partials.

Continuing the example above, if you have another file `_colors.scss`, you can use a variable `$red` from it in your `_mixin.scss`, if you declare importing it in `screen.scss` in proper order:

```
@import "path_to_your_partials/colors" // has a mixin colorize
@import "path_to_your_partials/mixin"  // has a variable $red
@import "path_to_your_partials/header"
```

and in your partial `_header.scss`, you can use both mixin from `_mixins.scss` and a variable from `_colors.scss`:

```
@include colorize($red);
```

This way, when you change your file names for partials, you correct only names in your stand-alone .scss files, not across all the partials.

Comment: i must add `@import "my_mixin/mixin"` for every scss file if i want to use mixin from `my_mixin/mixin`, right ?

Comment: If your scss file is going to be compiled into css file separately, yes. If you have a `_mixin.scss`, and want to use it in `base.scss` and `print.scss`, you add `@import "path/mixin"` in both `base.scss` and `print.scss`. But if you want to use `_mixin.scss` in your `_header.scss` (partial), which is also included in `base.scss` and `print.scss` (stand-alone CSS), you don't need to include it again in your `_header.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any big problem here. As `print.scss` is separate CSS file (it doesn't have underscore at the beginning) it doesn't know what is `test_mixin` function. You should do the same as `screen.scss` file at the beginning:

```
@import "include/_mixin";
```

I also don't understand why you import `print.scss` file in your `screen.scss` file. For me it doesn't make any sense.

You can of course create one _init file and import it in each full scss file (not partial) for example:

```
@import "base/_init";
```

And in this `_init.scss` file you can add import rules. This way even if you change your file names you change them once in your `_init.scss` file.